# Los elementos de la escena en unity dejan de funcionar correctamente al agregar AR Camera e Image Target de Vuforia

Tags: unity3d, vuforia, realidad-aumentada

Estoy haciendo un juego de realidad aumentada tipo pong en **Unity 3d versión 2019.4.30f1** usando **Vuforia 8.5.9**, el movimiento es en 2d, todo lo que es la física de la pelota, colisiones, puntaje, el control de las paletas,etc. lo tengo hecho y funciona bien, el problema surge al agregar vuforia:

- Luego de agregar la AR Camera y el Image target a la escena y
  ajustarlo, detecta el image target y genera los
  elementos, pero la pelota y paletas dejan de comportarse igual y se
  salen de los límites de juego https://youtu.be/fk7RKN-FrdI

Este es el código de la bola

```
public class Bola : MonoBehaviour {

int speedX;
int speedY;
float speed;


//puntuacion
public Text puntajetexto;

int jugador1Puntaje = 0;
int jugador2Puntaje = 0;

//Ganador
public Text ganador;


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    moverbola();
}

void moverbola()
{
    speed = Random.Range(5, 10);
    speedX = Random.Range(0, 2);
    if (speedX == 0)
    {
        speedX = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        speedX = -1;
    }

    speedY = Random.Range(0, 2);
    if (speedY == 0)
    {
        speedY = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        speedY = -1;
    }
    float x = speed * speedX;
    float y = speed * speedY;
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    puntajetexto.text = jugador1Puntaje.ToString() + " - " + jugador2Puntaje.ToString();

    if (jugador1Puntaje == 2)
    {
        ganador.text = "Jugador 1 Gana";
        ganador.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        resetearPelota();
    }

    if (jugador2Puntaje == 2)
    {
        ganador.text = "Jugador 2 Gana";
        ganador.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        resetearPelota();
    }
}


void OnCollisionEnter(Collision objeto)
{
    if(objeto.collider.tag == "jugador1anoto")
    {
        jugador2Puntaje++;
        resetearPelota();
        Invoke("moverbola",2);
    }

    if (objeto.collider.tag == "jugador2anoto")
    {
        jugador1Puntaje++;
        resetearPelota();
        moverbola();
        Invoke("moverbola", 2);
    }
}


void resetearPelota()
{
    transform.localPosition = new Vector3(3, 0, 0);
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = Vector3.zero;
}
```

}